# How to determine whether those sets are open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given those three sets below, A (left), B (center) and C (right), with A, B, C $\subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$, how can I determine, whether they are open or closed in metric space terminology via simplest way?

Set A is a closed set, set B is open set and set C is a closed set with a hole with boundary in center of it.
[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you call $A,B,C$ metric spaces. Surely you don't mean to say that.

Comment: I can see what the first and second ones are supposed to mean, but I don't know what the third one means.

Comment: @anakhronizein yeah, my fault, sorry. :-)

Comment: @Ian it means a set wit a hole in center of it.

Comment: you might want to describe in words what these figures mean.

Comment: So there's a hole, but is the boundary of the hole in the set whose open/closed property is under consideration, or not?

Comment: @Ian this hole has boundary in a set, so I have to make consideration based on it.

Comment: ...Let me be more specific. You have a closed square $S$. You have an open disk $D$, and the corresponding closed disk $\overline{D}$. Is your third set $S \setminus D$ or $S \setminus \overline{D}$ ?

Comment: @Ian if I will translate my assignment to english, it's roughly equivalent will be "a square with a circular hole in it". I'm not sure what author has ment. I am sorry for not being so informative, this task is a part of my high-school science fair project and I've just begun learning basics of metric spaces.

Comment: I can answer both questions. If it is $S \setminus D$, then the set is closed (since you have removed an open set from a closed set). If it is $S \setminus \overline{D}$, then it is neither open nor closed (this is analogous to the situation of a half-open interval in 1D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set, in a metric space, is "open" if and only if it contains **none** of its boundary points.  If I am correct in interpreting the "dashed" boundary on the second square as meaning that those points are not in the set, then that set is open.

A set, in a metric space, is "closed" if and only if it contains **all** of its boundary points.  If I am correct in interpreting the "solid" boundary on the first and third sets as meaning that those points are in the set, then that set is closed.

Of course, if a set contains some but not all of its boundary points then it is neither open nor closed.

It is even possible for a set to be **both** open **and** closed if it has **no** boundary points.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the only such sets are the empty set and $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

A set is called open if every point of s has a neighborhood that consists of entirely from points that belong set S. Now think about it, if there is no boundary, we can find new points by just magnifying it, there are infinitely many of them. But if there is boundary, then choose a point on boundary. The neighborhood of this points has some points that does not belong to original set.